# Auto run python file when usb inserted

Tags: python, usb, autorun

I have a Raspberry Pi running Linux. My plan is that I can plug in a USB in the robot and have and it will run the python files. the reason I chose this method is that it allows for easy editing and debugging of the scripts.

Is there a way to execute my files when the USB is inserted?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use os.path.exists to detect whether the pendrive is there in an infinite loop and when detected execute code on pendrive using os.system and break out of loop .

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1648939

Looks like you should consider writing a script that navigates to the directory of the file and runs "python yourscript.py". The details on getting the script to autorun are there.